# Export flutter PATH makes docker cli and/or npm not working

Tags: docker, flutter, npm

I have the following problem.

I noticed that, once i installed flutter and added its path to my .zshrc file, like this

```
export PATH={$PATH}:/Users/matteo/Documents/flutter/bin
```

I have problems with docker and/or npm. (E.G. I get the error docker: command not found)
I tried moving my line of code in different places in my .zshrc file, and it seems like depending on where my line of code is placed, sometimes only docker is not found, sometimes only npm, sometimes both of them.

Are there any connection, maybe under the hood, between those 3 application?

My computer is a Macbook Pro with Big Sur 11.4 and M1 chip.

Thanks for help,

Matteo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are exporting the path the wrong way, you should add it as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/matteo/Documents/flutter/bin"
```

After you have updated the ".zshrc" file, run this command to ensure changes have been notified to OS

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Reference: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos